# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [name, xpath, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled

Tags: java, xpath, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

All xpaths are upto date and still iam getting this below issue whenever i run the script.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [uiAutomator, accessibility, className, id, tagName, name, xpath, linkText, partialLinkText, windowsAutomation, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled

  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [uiAutomator, accessibility, className, id, tagName, name, xpath, linkText, partialLinkText, windowsAutomation, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.getFilledValue(AppiumByBuilder.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.createBy(AppiumByBuilder.java:148)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.getBys(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildMobileNativeBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:66)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:53)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:56)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at com.hlb.mobileautomation.pages.AccountSummaryPage.<init>(AccountSummaryPage.java:22)
    at com.hlb.mobileautomation.stepdefinitions.MainSteps.user_navigates_to_quick_links_for_send_money(MainSteps.java:263)
    at ✽.Then user navigates to quick links for send money(src/test/resources/features/FundTranferFavoriteAccount.feature:37)
```

Failed scenarios:
src/test/resources/features/FundTranferFavoriteAccount.feature:43 # Scenario Outline: Log in the app for the first time

```
1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 3 passed)
2m2.672s

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [uiAutomator, accessibility, className, id, tagName, name, xpath, linkText, partialLinkText, windowsAutomation, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.getFilledValue(AppiumByBuilder.java:109)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.bys.builder.AppiumByBuilder.createBy(AppiumByBuilder.java:148)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.getBys(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:133)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildMobileNativeBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:182)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.DefaultElementByBuilder.buildBy(DefaultElementByBuilder.java:216)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:66)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:53)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumElementLocatorFactory.createLocator(AppiumElementLocatorFactory.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultFieldDecorator.decorate(DefaultFieldDecorator.java:56)
    at io.appium.java_client.pagefactory.AppiumFieldDecorator.decorate(AppiumFieldDecorator.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:105)
    at com.hlb.mobileautomation.pages.AccountSummaryPage.<init>(AccountSummaryPage.java:22)
    at com.hlb.mobileautomation.stepdefinitions.MainSteps.user_navigates_to_quick_links_for_send_money(MainSteps.java:263)
    at ✽.Then user navigates to quick links for send money(src/test/resources/features/FundTranferFavoriteAccount.feature:37)

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 125.135 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
feature(com.hlb.mobileautomation.runner.RunCukesTest)  Time elapsed: 123.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [uiAutomator, accessibility, className, id, tagName, name, xpath, linkText, partialLinkText, windowsAutomation, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled
    at com.hlb.mobileautomation.runner.RunCukesTest.feature(RunCukesTest.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy19: one of [uiAutomator, accessibility, className, id, tagName, name, xpath, linkText, partialLinkText, windowsAutomation, iOSClassChain, iOSNsPredicate] should be filled
```

Results :

Failed tests:

```
RunCukesTest.feature:39 » Cucumber java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @$Proxy...
```

I used page object model with cucumber.

Comment: can you show how you implement your page object model? i think you didn't assign xpath, id or accessibilityId

Comment: thank you @SubanDhyako for giving hint. It seems like even if it is empty it will give the same error. I post this solution below for others as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'm Using page factory with cucumber.

This issue occurs when you have LOCATORS VALUE EMPTY in any java class.

For e.g-:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath="")
@AndroidFindBy(id="vn.com.nitin.test.uat:id/hamburger_menu")
private MobileElement hamburger_menu;
```

So i searched all locators in java class page factory and I entered all corrected and updated xpath, id, link etc.

After that everything works fine for me.

Probably this will help for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make it clear here, the error cause is because of empty Xpath:

```
@AndroidFindBy(xpath = "")
private MobileElement abc;
```